# router flapping after plugging in server

Tags: networking, wifi

After a lot of troubleshooting, I now believe my server is causing my router to flap up and down.

I pinged the router all night and it showed zero packet loss, but after pluggin in my server, it's up and down like a yoyo. I have tried using Wifi instead of via patch lead, but with the same result.

What could be causing this? I tried downloading ethereal to monitor the traffic, but their installer seems to be corrupt no matter what mirror I chose.

Comment: Forgot to mention, my server is Windows 2003 R2 SP2. Hewlett Packard ML115 G5

Comment: When you say "it is up and down like a yoyo" are you referring to the router or the server?  How are you establishing up or down or flapping?  What happens to the other devices on your network?  Have you got console access to your router, and do you know what to do if you have this?

Comment: The server makes the router external IP address flap up and down. As soon as I unplug the server, the router settles back down.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't configured your server with the same IP address as your router have you?

Comment: No.. It's set to 192.168.1.1 - the router is 192.168.1.254

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually Apache, which was part of Xampp. It continuously flooded the network with packets. I found it by pure chance, just by switching off services. I started down the list with "A". I havent found out why apache was doing that, but I'm just relieved to people accessing the server again.